# How to integrate Geb, Spock and Allure Report

Tags: spock, geb, allure

I have been trying to integrate the Allure report with Geb and Spock framework But I am not able to make.

As Allure report has its own command to run the test and similarly Geb and Spock has its own to run the test. How do I combine the both to run the test

Allure Report Command : ./gradlew clean build allureReport
Geb and Spock Command : ./gradlew chromeTest

How do I combine both to run the Chrome test and get the Allure Result

You help is appreciated

Comment: Can anybody help me on this please. I am awaiting for response.

Comment: Hi @Szymon Stepniak, Can you please help me on the above issue

Comment: Welcome to SO. As a new user please first learn how to write an MCVE, then edit your question in order to be an MCVE and dramatically improve the probability of getting a helpful answer. :-)